# THREE.js shadows all centered in the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've combined a couple of the examples from the three.js documentation and also added `mesh.castShadow = true` on the generated meshes from the Glitch post-processing example. However, if you look at the jsfiddle below, you can see that all of the shadows are converging in the middle. I would maybe expect this from the hemisphere lighting, however, hemisphere lighting doesn't cast shadows. Any ideas?

The jsfiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/24458kbf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very narrow shadow camera. Try changing your `d` to 500. Also your directional light is positioned within your objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Changing the d definitely did the trick. I'm not sure I understand what you mean regarding the directional light being positioned within my objects. Does making the `d` value larger make this _not_ the case?

Comment: Also, is it common practice to set the `d` value to the maximum z of any mesh in the scene?

Comment: If your light is vertically on top of your objects then the bounding box of your scene is a good measure of what d should be. But in the case you would use different d for shadow camera values.